# How to preserve content generated by user on KitKat+?

Tags: android, application-design, android-external-storage

This more of design rather than technical question... On KitKat Google blocked writing to SD cards except designated application folder. It's ok for applications that just show content, but what about applications that generate content (I mean users generate content with the help of that application: documents, databases, statistics data)? My concern is that if application is uninstalled then all the data is erased by system. This behavior is not expected by majority of users, they just wont think about that. And what do users do when application does not work as they expect? Yes, try to reinstall it as the first solution. Losing all their user files! Backing them up on a cloud could be an option but SD storage is primary used for large files, it would be expensive to backup them over mobile network.

So the question is to developers of such applications: what approach did you take to overcome that restriction consequences?

Answer (score 0):

just as always have been

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myApp/");
folder.mkdirs();
File file = new File(folder, "file.jpg");

// open output stream and write to it... works fine...
```

that works as it should on any version of Android.

As far as I understood, the restriction on KitKat is that, after you called `folder.mkdirs();` other apps won't be able to access it. On Android a new user is created for each app, that how they control/block the permissions, so I believe what changed in KitKat (really not sure and just guessing here) is that every file creation marks that file as read/write just by the owner and no one else.